# Compiling error: memory dump file and forward search

Tags: memory

I am struggling with my miktex installation for a while and don't seem to get it working just right. I did however, manage to install everything just fine on my other Laptop, so I figure, the problem must be some stupid detail.

I am using Miktex2.9 with TexnicCenter on a Win7 Professional machine. I had previously installed and deinstalled miktex a couple of times on my c:\programs because i thought that way I could solve the problems. Didn't work. Since the deinstallation via Windowns didn't succeed, I manually deinstalled it and cleaned the registry from anything that said "miktex". In my command-window I checked the paths, but couldn't find any miktex-path. There should be one, right?

So, then I installed miktex again. This time as single-user, not in c:\programs (d:\miktex, this time), as suggested in this forum, with "Install packages on the fly - yes".

I want to compile HelloWorld.tex which consists of

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

and get the following two error messages, when compiling to pdf:

First Message:

[image]

I get the same message when trying to compile via the command window.
The mentioned logfile says:

```
2016-02-24 15:31:11,142+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2016-02-24 15:31:11,142+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2016-02-24 15:31:11,142+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2016-02-24 15:31:11,143+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 622
```

Could you tell me how to solve this issue?

The second message the (well-known?) pop-up window saying:

[image]

I am using Sumatra as PDF viewer, however don't believe that this is the issue. Since no pdf file is procuded whatsoever. In fact, right now not even .tps, .bbl., .aux., .log, .out or .synctex is produced.

The command-window gives the following answer after typing `pdflatex --version`

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5840 (1.40.16) (MiKTeX 2.9)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2014 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.  
compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8 
compiled with libpng version 1.6.19; using 1.6.19
compiled with poppler version 0.32.0
compiled with jpeg version 8.4
```

Like mentioned before, there is no miktex entry in the paths when checking with `set`in the command window.

I would be really glad if you could give me a hint as to what I did wrong, since I have been trying to repair for quite a while now. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I have a very similar problem (except for the line : "FATAL pdflatex - Line: 640") while trying to setup a portable version with MiKTeX and TexStudio on a USB drive. An answer would be very welcome!